# MYSQL CASE Condition Didn't Met

Tags: mysql

I have an **Order_Table** table. This table column is something like this

```
Order Code | Code |     Create Time     |      Pick Time       |      Pack Time
Order1       A01    2019-11-15 09:25:30    2019-11-15 13:10:23   2019-11-15 14:51:36
Order2       A02    2019-11-15 15:33:31    2019-11-15 15:48:14           NULL
Order3       A03    2019-11-14 18:00:30          NULL                    NULL
```

**Create Time** is the time when the order is created,
**Pick Time** is the time when store pick the order to process it,
**Pack Time** is the time when store pack the order to sent it

So I need to create a report to become something like this

```
Order Code | Code |  Last Update Time  |
Order1       A01    2019-11-15 14:51:36
Order2       A02    2019-11-15 15:48:14         
Order3       A03    2019-11-14 18:00:30
```

**Last Update Time** is the latest status time from the order (e.g. **Order1** latest status is pack, so **Last Update Time** will get the **Pack Time** from **Order1**). This is my query:

```
SELECT
   order_code
   , code
   , CASE
        WHEN pack_time IS NOT NULL THEN pack_time
        WHEN pack_time IS NULL THEN pick_time
        WHEN pick_time IS NULL THEN create_time
        ELSE '-'
     END AS 'Last Update Time'
FROM Order_Table
```

My query can't seems to get the **Create Time** value for **Order3** even though the **pack_time** and **pick_time** is null. It didnt even catch the ELSE statement.

```
Order Code | Code |  Last Update Time  |
Order1       A01    2019-11-15 14:51:36
Order2       A02    2019-11-15 15:48:14         
Order3       A03          NULL
```

Comment: Note that 'order' is reserved word in MySQL, rendering it a poor choice as a table/column identifier

Comment: @Strawberry oh I'm sorry, I'm kinda new to MySQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `COALESCE()` for that:

```
    SELECT
       order_code,
       code,
       COALESCE(pack_time, pick_time, create_time) AS 'Last Update Time'
    FROM order
```

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen. In this case it will, but that's only because of the physical proces, these real-life events can't be done in a different order.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to use the `GREATEST` scalar function along with `COALESCE`, having each of the three dates defer to the two others when `NULL`, in order:

```
SELECT
    order_code,
    code,
    GREATEST(COALESCE(create_time, pick_time, pack_time),
             COALESCE(pick_time, create_time, pack_time),
             COALESCE(pack_time, create_time, pick_time)) AS last_update_time
FROM order_table;
```